# How to override notification configuration for specific notification only?

Tags: reactjs, notifications, react-toastify

I use `react-toastify` for notifications in my React app. In its configuration I've set a default `autoClose` setting. Is there a way that I can override this setting for specific notifications only? Please find my current code below.

---

I set `react-toastify` default configuration in the index page:

```
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
<ToastContainer
    closeButton={false}
    autoClose={6000}
/>
```

On other pages I for example have the code blow. It's there where I would like to set a custom configuration for `autoClose` for that specific message only.

```
    Notify({
        message: `A message`,
    });
```

This uses a component called Notify:

```
const User = ({ message, closeToast }) => (
    <div key={0} className="notification">
        <span style={{ backgroundImage: `url('/icons/user.svg')` }}></span>
        <label dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message }}></label>
        <button onClick={closeToast}>+</button>
    </div>
);

const Notification = (props) => {
    const { message, user } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            toast(<User message={message} />, {
                className: "white-background",
                bodyClassName: "grow-font-size",
                progressClassName: "fancy-progress-bar",
            })
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for react-toastify, you can pass the autoClose prop into the toast() emitter, as well as the ToastContainer

```
toast('My message', {autoClose: 5000});
```

https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/introduction/